# What is the difference between Promise.all vs. x => Promise.all(x) in a promise chain?

Tags: javascript, closures, anonymous-function

I've been trying to get an array of promises to resolve all at the same time. I know that Promise.prototype.then() takes a callback which accepts the resolved value:

```js
const one = Promise.resolve(1)

one.then( console.log ) // 1
one.then( x => console.log(x) ) // 1
```

When I try to invoke Promise.all on an array of promises, I have to use a callback to make it work.

```js
const two = Promise.resolve(2)
const three = Promise.resolve(3)

Promise.resolve([two, three])
  .then( xs => Promise.all(xs) ) // Works
  .then( console.log ) // [2,3]
  
Promise.resolve([two,three])
  .then( Promise.all ) // Error
  .then( console.log )
```

What's going on here? Why can't I just pass in Promise.all and have it work as the callback function? Why do I have to 'manually' call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Promise.all` expects to be called with `Promise`* as the `this` object. This would work (but be more verbose than the arrow function):

```
Promise.resolve([two, three])
  .then(Promise.all.bind(Promise))
  .then(console.log)
```

* Technically, this is specified [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.all); it can be called on another constructor that is similar to `Promise` in a number of ways, but in practice you'll want to use `Promise` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but isn't this what you're trying to accomplish:

```
const one = Promise.resolve(1);
const two = Promise.resolve(2);
const three = Promise.resolve(3);

Promise.all([one,two,three]).then(console.log);
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, I was working on a longer chain and somewhere in the middle I had an array of promises to resolve. I tried adding`.then(Promise.all)` , which, *interestingly*, didn't work, leading to this question.